# Finding the inner product generated by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> In each part, use the given inner product on **$R^2$** to find $\|\vec w\|$, where $\vec w\ = (-1, 3)$.
>
> Then the problem lists different inner products to use to find the norm but the one I'm having trouble understanding is this:
>
> Use the inner product generated by the matrix A = $\bigl(\begin{matrix}
> 1&2\\ -1&3
> \end{matrix} \bigr)$

I'm sort of at a loss as how to get this into a weighted Euclidean inner product. I know there's a couple equations to use here but I'm not sure how to use them to get what I want, the textbook also points out that the weighted Euclidean inner product is given by a diagonal matrix where everything on the diagonal gives you the weight to use. I think that's what I'm supposed to be looking for, I simply don't understand how to get there from the given matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more examining of my textbook, I came up with something that might be the answer, though I'd call it sketchy at best. I'd really like to understand this for when finals time rolls around, so if someone could tell me if I'm correct or not (and if not, why) I'd appreciate it very much.

> Using equation 6.1.5:
>
> > <$\vec u$, $\vec v$> = $\vec v^TA^TA\vec u$
>
> for the purposes of finding $\|\vec w\|$ the inner product can be represented as 
>   $<\vec w, \vec w> = \vec w^TA^TA\vec w $
>
> where $\vec w = \bigl(\begin{matrix} -1\\3 \end{matrix})$ and 
>   $ A = \bigl(\begin{matrix} 1&2\\ -1&3 \end{matrix} \bigr)$.
>
> $\therefore \|\vec w\|=\sqrt{<\vec w, \vec w>}=\sqrt{125} = 5\sqrt5$

Comment: Yes, this must be it. The idea is to transform the vectors first by the linear transformation, and then use the usual dot product. $(Au)\cdot(Av)=(Au)^TAv=u^TA^TAv$.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that this is the answer?:

$$(x_1,y_1).(x_2,y_2) = (x_1,y_1)\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_2\\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

It is not commutative, but at least it is a single value :-).